# useradd fails on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, useradd

testing out archlinux in a vm by following a tutorial on youtube.. all is fine up until the point where i reboot, boot with the hard disk and enter `root` at the login screen.

i am trying to add a new user with the useradd function like the guy does in his [walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ozjwvGYhhvM#t=544s).

I enter:

```
useradd -m -g users -G lp, scanner, audio, video, optical, storage, network, power, games, wheel -s /bin/bash iKlsR
```

upon entering that i get this error

> useradd: group `` does not exist

I followed his instructions as closely as possible yet his works and mine doesn't, is the syntax accurate and or there any pitfalls to adding a user this way, im thinking about trying the interactive `adduser` but im interested in what this does and understanding the switches etc.

Comment: What happens when you leave out the spaces in `lp, scanner, au.........`?

Comment: I don't understand.. ? The above happens.. wait, i will try again and remove the spaces.

Comment: got it, that fixed it!

Comment: indeed, your original command was, for the program: `-G lp,`  which means `groups: 'lp',''` (and the `''` (empty string) group doesn't exist. The rest was not even processed yet, or would have created additionnal errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
useradd -m -g users -G lp,scanner,audio,video,optical,storage,network,power,games,wheel -s /bin/bash iKlsR
```

Comment: yh i tried and it worked.. seems rather silly tho..

Comment: see my comment on your original post above for the explanation ^^. Computers or commands are not exactly silly, they do what we ask them to do ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add a new user by typing the command:

```
useradd -G wheel -s /bin/bash -m "$username" -c "$fullusername"
```

which is quite often sufficient for the need of a lambda user.

Example: Malory ARCHER client wants to have a userspace on my machine. The command would be:

```
useradd -G wheel -s /bin/bash -m "malory" -c "Malory ARCHER"
```